# Is it possible to block a webpage from using a facebook pixel?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

With all the recent outrage around Facebook, the biggest problem concerning privacy seems to be the tracking of browsing behaviour by placing a so called "facebook pixel" on webpages.

Is there a way (add-on, userscript, etc.) to block webpages from using these pixels?

I'm personally using Chrome, so would be most interested in that, but more general answers are definitely welcome too.

Comment: Are you looking for ways to block Facebook tracking in your browsing session, or from Facebook interacting in any way with a website you built/manage?

Comment: Also, any competent AdBlock plugin would do precisely this. AdBlocking utilities don't care that Facebook is only using a "pixel" of a page.

Comment: @music2myear I'm looking for the former, and I wasn't aware that adblockers already blocked these kinds of things. You could turn that into an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Existing AdBlockers will generally already contain support for blocking Facebook-based ads. To block tracking, you'd need to select whichever settings are appropriate for tracking protection.

The size of the entity you wish to block has no bearing on whether it can be blocked by existing privacy and tracking protection tools.